# セコム・ホームセキュリティとの連携サービスのように、aiboのカメラ映像をアプリに取り込みたい

Tags: aibo-developer

aiboの内蔵カメラから取り込んだ映像をpythonプログラムに取り込む方法には どのようなものがありますでしょうか？ また、Web APIなどからaiboに写真を撮る命令を出すことはできますでしょうか？

Comment: 残念ながらこちらはプログラミングについて扱うサイトになります。製品の仕様だったり、機能に関する部分「教育機関向けに公開してもらうことなどはできないものでしょうか？」はSonyに問い合わせするほうがよろしいかと思います。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。それでは質問を変えます。
aiboの内蔵カメラから取り込んだ映像をpythonプログラムに取り込む方法には
どのようなものがありますでしょうか？
また、Web APIなどからaiboに写真を撮る命令を出すことはできますでしょうか？

Comment: 質問を変える場合はコメントに記述するのではなくて、直接質問を[編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/71061/edit)してください。

Answer (score 1):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

> aiboの内蔵カメラから取り込んだ映像をスマホに転送しています。
> 同様のことをやりたいのですが、aibo Web APIのドキュメントに関連する記述が
> 見当たりませんでした。一般公開していないということなのでしょうか。

現時点で aibo が撮影した画像や動画を取得する API は公開しておりません。

> これを教育機関向けに公開してもらうことなどはできないものでしょうか？

これらのご相談につきましては、Stackoverflow にて相談済みである旨を添えて
aibo オーナーサポートへメールにてお問い合わせください。

#### aibo オーナーサポート

**https://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/_contact**

> 「aiboの飼い方、ご購入前の相談など、aiboに関するすべてのお問い合わせは以下のaibo専用窓口へお問い合わせください。」

**メールでのお問い合わせ**
　**https://www.sony.jp/support/aibo/inquiry_mail/?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/contact/_mail**

> 上記リンク先において、注意事項に同意いただいた上、
> 「同意してメールで問い合わせる」ボタンを押してください。

また、Stackoverflow への質問はプログラミングのことに限定していただきますようお願いいたします。
詳しくはこちらをご参照ください。
https://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/_contact#devevisu

・質問の例
「〇〇のプログラムを実行したいのですが、どうすればできますか？」
「APIでエラーが発生します。原因は何でしょうか？」

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム